# How to use a position:relative DIV act as a 'spacer' for other divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container with a bunch of equally sized elements. The container has a width of 100% up to a certain px amount, so if a user shrinks their screen down, elements from the first row may be moved down to the second row to fit, and from the second row to the third row, etc.

I'd like the `.spacer` div to act as a pseudo margin so that the first element in the second row of divs, no matter what div it actually is, will be spaced 250px out from the left side of the container. I want that `.spacer` div to always remain at a fixed point relative to the container (right at the beginning of the second row) but also affect the position of the first div in that row. How can I accomplish this with CSS? Open to JS solutions as well.

Here's a Codepen that shows the situation I'm describing:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMMyLj

Any ideas?

Comment: can you be more specific? a visual representation of what you want to achieve'll be helpful

Comment: @ErrorinException Check out the codepen above, should give a good representation of what I'm looking for. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMMyLj

Comment: I did the red div is on the third row. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @ErrorinException For me the red div is in the middle of the second row. Weird. Either way I need that red div to be able to stay in it's position, but also affect the position of the white divs. So that the red div is not over the white div, but rather it pushes the white div to the right.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for, but change `float: right` and `margin-right: 10px` on your `.square`

Comment: @user8345012 Does my answer fulfil your question?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but check if you are looking something like this:

```css
.container {
  background-color: black;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1800px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: white;
  float: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 250px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
  <div class="square">1</div>
  <div class="square">2</div>
  <div class="square">3</div>
  <div class="square">4</div>
  <div class="square">5</div>
  <div class="square">6</div>
  <div class="square">7</div>
  <div class="square">8</div>
  <div class="square">9</div>
  <div class="square">10</div>
  <div class="square">11</div>
  <div class="square">12</div>
  <div class="square">13</div>
  <div class="square">14</div>
  <div class="square">15</div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you see a red div in the output of codepen? that div should be placed just before the first div in the second row only. This answer didn't answer the question

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible solution using css grid and variables. It uses css-grid to layout the red spacer, and javascript to update the number of columns required. (Note that they are only supported in modern browsers http://caniuse.com/css-grid/embed)

CSS

```
:root {
    --colNum: 1;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: left;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--colNum), auto);
}

.square {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: white;
}

.spacer {
  background-color: red; 
  width: 250px;
  grid-row: 2 / span 1;
  grid-col: 1 / span 1;
}
```

JS

```
function setNoOfColumns(){
  columns = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 250);
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--colNum", columns);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
  setNoOfColumns();
});

setNoOfColumns();
```

Code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mMMPwO